# Unable to run the Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am following some [TUTORIAL](http://4dev.tech/2016/03/login-screen-and-authentication-with-angular2/) for a simple login example and I am using Angulario latest version. I tried to understand the logic and downloaded the code from [REPOSITORY](https://github.com/leonardohjines/angular2-login), but can someone help me to see this in action? After downloading the project I just changed the directory to downloaded folder and then issued `npm install` and then issued `ng serve` , but it's giving me different errors like angular.json couldn't be found etc., Have searched online to overcome these errors, but no luck. I think I am making blunder, but please go easy as I am new to Angular.

Comment: It is a version conflict

Comment: You seem to be using Angular 6 (where angular.json is added and another .json isn't used anymore). You have to explicitly specify which angular version you're using in the package.json or be better off starting with an Angular 6 project (or template/tutorial).

Comment: i dont see a angular.json file in the repo. I would recommend to create a new angular project and move the componets from the cloned repo to that new project

Comment: post the errors here and also your angular version

Comment: Are you inside the correct folder and executing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

It is a version conflict. from angular6 requires new file angular.json which is not found on your project.

Try running 
`ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4`

Comment: I did this already and it says package not installed angular-cli skipping and then I issued again ng serve, but same error

Comment: delete the node modules folder and issue npm install then do ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4